# Set request variables for functional testing of controllers in rails with minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, request, minitest

When doing functional tests for controllers in rails how can I provide dynamic application instance variables to my test which live in the request.

I have a `@station` object that is initialized in a `before action` in my application controller (available in all other controllers), however the `@station` object is defined by the domain entry of the user e.g.: `blue.mydomain.com`. So it could have 3 different flavors, and the controller actions `params[:id]` are only valid for a certain flavor.

Further if I don't give my @station a flavor for my test environment it will fail utterly:
 (Here code from a helper that gets called in a before action in my application_controller.rb)

```
def init_station
    if Rails.env == "test"
      @station=Station.new('blue')
    else
      @station=Station.new(domain_flavor_picker)
    end
end


ApplicationController
 ....
 before_action :init_station
 .....

end
```

Thus I can only test for 'blue' or switch the flavor in my before action and then mock for different id!

test:

```
describe MyController do

    before do
        @id="10215d8da3f4f278cec747f09985b5528ec9e"         
    end

    it "should get index action" do
        p assigns(:station) # is nil
        get :artist_biography, id: @id, locale: I18n.available_locales.sample
        assert_response :success
        assert_not_nil assigns(:meta)           
        assert_not_nil assigns(:nav)
        assert_not_nil assigns(:content)
    end
end
```

As you can see I am also in need of providing a locale variable. I managed to mix up that call with `I18n.available_locales.sample`

How can I dynamically switch or manipulate my @station instance variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that I needed to provide minitest with an initial host! From @smathy answer I knew that I needed a **Mock Request** for the Controller!

Turns out that it is quite easy to set it in MiniTest if you know how!

Rails provides an `ActionDispatch::TestRequest` object which in itself seems to be a `Rack::MockRequest` object:

```
DEFAULT_ENV = Rack::MockRequest.env_for('/', 'HTTP_HOST' => 'test.host', 'REMOTE_ADDR' => '0.0.0.0', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Rails Testing' )
```

So all I had to do in my test was:

```
before do
  @request.env['HTTP_HOST'] = %w(blue.mydomain.com red.mydomain.com green.mydomain.com).sample
end
```

to initialize my @station object with a sample of flavored domains.

Answer (score 0):

`assigns :station` will only return a value **after** you do the request, ie. after the `get` line.  Until you've done the request none of your controller code has been run for that test.

You also shouldn't use `@vars` in rspec, use `let` instead, and a few other things that I've shown below, [many of which I learned from BetterSpecs](http://betterspecs.org/)

#### The Crux of your Issue

Assuming that `domain_flavor_picker` is a method in your controller then you should just mock that so you can different tests for the different return values of it.  So, this shows the context for one of the return values of `domain_flavor_picker`, but you'd add other contexts for other values:

```
describe MyController do

  let(:id) { "10215d8da3f4f278cec747f09985b5528ec9e" }

  describe "GET /artist_biography" do
    context "when domain_flavor is blue" do
      before do
        allow(controller).to receive(:domain_flavor_picker) { "blue" } # <-- MOCK!
      end

      context "when valid id" do
        before { get :artist_biography, id: id, locale: I18n.available_locales.sample }

        subject { response }
        it { is_expected.to be_success }
        it "should assign :meta" do
          expect(assigns :meta).to be_present     # better to have an actual matcher here
        end
        it "should assign :nav" do
          expect(assigns :nav).to be_present      # ditto
        end
        it "should assign :content" do
          expect(assigns :content).to be_present  # ditto
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is minitest not rspec

Comment: I'll look into let and mocking a bit deeper, however does not rails initialize the whole environment and thus provide the @station to the test?

Comment: Both init_station and domain_flavor_picker are application_helper.rb methods, not of the controller I am testing

Comment: Where the method is defined (ie. where it is in the call-stack) isn't important, what's important is where it's being called **from**.  You're showing `domain_flavor_picker` as being called in the context of your controller, so if you mock it on the controller then that mocked method will receive the method call from within `init_station` (of course you'd need to remove the `Rails.env == 'test'` condition.

Comment: ...and no, Rails does not call your controller's `before_action`s or any other methods in your controller until you actually initiate a request to an action.

Comment: ...and re being minitest, sorry, I saw the `describe` and assumed you were using rspec. But the issue here is really just mocking the `domain_flavor_picker` method (or even the `init_station` method if you'd prefer) properly to setup your `@station` in a predictable way that you can test for.

Comment: Thanks for all the insights, they are much appreciated!